# Large tags pushes out score and post count in profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

I happened to come across this in a random profile.

Please see below screenshot:

[image]

It happens in

- Chrome stable(Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)) Mac Sierra
- Safari (Version 11.0.3 (12604.5.6.1.1)) in Mac Sierra.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on *Windows* computer, seems to be a **Mac-only problem** ... By the way, when testing this in Internet explorer `SCORE` and `POSTS` are not aligned (like in the picture from OP)

Comment: Cross-site duplication in MSE [Tag name overflow on “top tags” section of user profile if tag name is long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306372/312043)

Comment: No repro, Chrome 65.0.3325.146, Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 58.0.2 (32 bit), Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit ([yet another pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Es11.png))

Comment: Problem *does* reproduce for me on Chrome 65.0.3325.146, Windows 10 64-bit for the examples in the linked MSE post.

Comment: In IE 11.0.10240.17770 it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6fCq.png) for me.

Comment: Happens for me as well on Chrome 65 with this profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9294285/amplience-support